# What Bluetooth stack supports HFP on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth

I am looking for a Bluetooth stack for Windows XP that supports HFP. Here is what I have found so far:

- Wildcomm - HFP not supported or no one has be able to enable it.
- Microsoft - support for HFP in their embedded platforms.
- Toshiba - supports HFP, but their Bluetooth stack seems to be only for their products.

Has anyone had any luck using HFP with any Bluetooth stack on Windows XP? In addition to the audio connection, I also need the hands-free signals to answer and hang-up a call.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it helps you much, but some information anyway...  The Microsoft Bluetooth stack on Windows XP does not support SCO, see http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-device-drivers/297889-how-can-i-get-sco-data-based-micrisoft-bluetoot-stack.html

Vista added support for it, and Windows 7 adds in-the-box support for HFP (and HSP, A2DP and AVRCP).  See section "slide 15" at http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20in%20Windows%207.html

So seems unlikely that a third-party one can add HFP support to XP+MSFT. :-(